# Getting ValidationError while creating s3 bucket using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am new to cloudformation template. Using codepipeline I am trying to create one s3 bucket. This is the cloudformation template:

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Template to create buckets and copy ymls to S3.

Parameters:
  SPABucket:
    Description: S3 bucket name for backend lambda functions
    Type: String
    Default: reference-data-migration-bucket-2021   
  
Resources:
  S3Bucketxls:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
        BucketName: !Sub ${SPABucket}-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true
        VersioningConfiguration:
          Status: Enabled
        AccessControl: Private
        LoggingConfiguration:
          DestinationBucketName: !Ref SpaLoggingBucket
          LogFilePrefix: S3Bucketxls
        BucketEncryption: 
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: 'AES256'          
        Tags:
        - Key: "sample"
          Value: "test"

    SpaLoggingBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:       
        AccessControl: Private
        Tags:
        - Key: "sample"
          Value: "test"
        

Outputs:
  S3Bucketxlsx:
    Description: The CodeDeploy role for a particular business service being deployed
    Value: !GetAtt S3Bucketxls.Arn
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-S3BucketxlsArn"
```

I am getting validation error while doing Lint using codepipeline:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate
> operation: Invalid template resource property 'SpaLoggingBucket'
>
> [Container] 2022/02/24 16:30:14 Command did not exit successfully aws
> cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://${TMPLNAME}
> exit status 254 [Container] 2022/02/24 16:30:14 Phase complete: BUILD
> State: FAILED [Container] 2022/02/24 16:30:14 Phase context status
> code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command:
> aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body
> file://${TMPLNAME}. Reason: exit status 254

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is important in YAML & it seems that your `SpaLoggingBucket` block is out of line with other resources like `S3Bucketxls`, making CloudFormation not detect it correctly as a resource.

Moving it one indentation level back works for me:

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Template to create buckets and copy ymls to S3.

Parameters:
  SPABucket:
    Description: S3 bucket name for backend lambda functions
    Type: String
    Default: reference-data-migration-bucket-2021   
  
Resources:
  S3Bucketxls:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
        BucketName: !Sub ${SPABucket}-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true
        VersioningConfiguration:
          Status: Enabled
        AccessControl: Private
        LoggingConfiguration:
          DestinationBucketName: !Ref SpaLoggingBucket
          LogFilePrefix: S3Bucketxls
        BucketEncryption: 
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: 'AES256'          
        Tags:
        - Key: "sample"
          Value: "test"

  SpaLoggingBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:       
      AccessControl: Private
      Tags:
      - Key: "sample"
        Value: "test"
        

Outputs:
  S3Bucketxlsx:
    Description: The CodeDeploy role for a particular business service being deployed
    Value: !GetAtt S3Bucketxls.Arn
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-S3BucketxlsArn"
```

P.S. one of the benefits of using JSON instead is not running into accidents like this.